# Actions to take after suspect PDF was opened

Tags: malware, ios, iphone, office

A colleague of mine opened a seemingly genuine PDF attached to an email. We run Office365 and normally malicious attachments are filtered out but this one slipped through. The PDF was opened on an iPhone and was password protected so it wasn't or seemed to be unopened. I'm leaning towards the idea that this attachment wasn't anything malicious but are there any steps we can take to ensure the host (iPhone) has not been compromised in any way?

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 2):

Except if you are a high profit organisation targeted by a highly sophisticated and well financed gov/cyber gang, or if the iPhone's OS is outdated and / or jailbreaked .. You have nothing to do since there are no actual risks, [the latest *known* serious flaw](https://citizenlab.org/2016/08/million-dollar-dissident-iphone-zero-day-nso-group-uae/) that could be exploited is patched on iOS 9.3.5.